# Jenkins GitHub disable auto commit status

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Jenkins with GitHub plugin. Everything works great except one thing.

How can I get rid of automatic commit statuses, like this one 
[image]

Desired behavior:

1. Push commits to GitHub (works!)
2. Trigger job (works!)
3. Set commit statuses via GitHub API (works!)
4. DO NOT set automatic commit statuses (NOT working)

GitHub plugin configuration
[image]

Comment: Can you post what build actions are associated with this job?

Comment: This happens automatically through the `github-organization-folder` plugin, without any explicit declaration to update the commit status. I'd also like to get rid of this for my test instance.

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin for Jenkins to add a setting for disabling commit statuses: [Disable GitHub Multibranch Status](https://plugins.jenkins.io/disable-github-multibranch-status/).